# Изменить расположение подписей для оси X

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Как в matplotlib подписи для оси X расположить не под делениями, а между делениями со сдвигом вправо?

Как сейчас есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как хотелось бы получить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основании [ответа с eng SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49449590/7927226), примерный вариант такой:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms


xs = ys = range(1, 14)  # тестовые значения
x_ticks_labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
    'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
x_ticks_posistion = [x for x in xs]  # начальные положения засечек по x

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs, ys)
ax = plt.gca()
dx = 0.2  # подобранное руками значение
dy = 0

# из ответа по ссылке, меняем положения засечек
offset = matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation(dx, dy, fig.dpi_scale_trans)
# apply offset transform to all x ticklabels.
for label in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    label.set_transform(label.get_transform() + offset)

plt.xticks(x_ticks_posistion, x_ticks_labels)

plt.xlim([min(xs), max(xs)])
```

[image: Result]

Для `dx` подходит величина в духе нескольких десятых от разности между соседними значениями `x`: (0.1:0.3)*(x_i - x_i-1). `dx` может быть меньше нуля, тогда свдиг произойдёт влево.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = mdates.drange(dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1), 
                      dt.datetime(2019,11,1), 
                      dt.timedelta(weeks=3))

counts = np.sin(np.linspace(0, np.pi, dates.size))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = np.diff(dates).min()

ax.bar(dates, counts, align='center', width=width)
ax.xaxis_date()
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем то. Нужно отображать месяц как я указал в примере